# how to check empty array from mysql in php

Tags: php

I have an array in php, this array is fetched from database. sometimes the array structure is like

```
array(""=>NULL)
```

but sometimes it's also contain actual data from the DB. but one thing for sure, it is never be an empty array `(array())`

how do i check if array is contain actual data?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check that array size ==1 and it contains a `""` array key and `NULL` is in the array.

Try like this:

```
   if(array_key_exists("",$array) && count($array) == 1 && in_array(NULL,$array)){
    echo "invalid";
   }
```

[demo](https://eval.in/112532)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `mysql` use `mysql_num_rows()`.. this will give you the count of `fetched results from table` .. so if the **count is 0** than your array is empty....

or you are using `PDO` than use `PDOstatement->rowCount()` ... and if you are using `mysqli` than use `mysqli_num_rows` to get the count...

Comment: Yes, use a [deprecated method](http://au2.php.net/mysql_num_rows) (no, don't really do this).

Comment: but he havent provided wether he is using `mysql` , `mysqli` or `pdo`.. Than I would have suggested different function..

Comment: I would update your answer to demonstrate the correct approach with both mysqli and PDO, and put your current answer underneath while flagging that it's deprecated.

Comment: PDO rowCount() is not reliable and its use is not suggested.

Comment: i forget to say that the value of the column is a serialized array. in select statement i select that field. i don't figure out yet why it always have count() > 0 (probably my bad coding). for now i use @Awlad Liton answer

Comment: @DarielPratama yes sure.. but can you please provide your `mysql` queries in your question.... so we can have more idea about it...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
if ($arr) {
  // there was an error
} else {
  // there wasn't
}
```

According to [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) the array to Boolean conversion will return false if the array contains only "NULL" as the value.

Answer (score 0):

***A very simple answer using php native functions***

```
$input_array = array(""=>NULL);
$is_error=array_filter($input_array);
if (!empty($is_error)) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if (!empty($result)
{
.....
}
```